# Does a tf.data.Dataset filled by tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices make a deep copy of the data?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

According to tensorflow, a tf.data.Dataset is a

"A Dataset can be used to represent an input pipeline as a collection of elements (nested structures of tensors) and a "logical plan" of transformations that act on those elements."

and when I import data using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices it

"Creates a Dataset whose elements are slices of the given tensors."

However, it is not clear to me if these nested tensors are filled with data that was hard copied, uses pointers to access the data, or works by reference. I am mainly concerned about if importing data using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices will make a hard copy of my data or not so that I don't run out of memory.

I tried benchmarking this with a small dataset by making two tf.data.Datasets from the same input data. I simply looked at how much memory the running program was using and in some cases it was half the size of the data, and in a second case (using half the data) I got strange results.